# C++ Force compiler to look for function in another header file, TCP socket programming, winsock.h

Tags: c++, sockets, tcpclient, omnet++

i'm doing trying to connect to a TCP Server within Eclipse/Omnet++. Therefore I have to create a socket using the standard definition defined in winsock.h header file:

```cpp
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

This results in the following error:

```
veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc:69:48: error: no match for call to '(inet::UdpSocket) (int, int, int)'
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

The problem here is that as I'm within the Eclipse/omnet++ network simulator environment, the compiler thinks I want to do a "socket" simulation within omnet++ (which is the standard use case of course) but I want to "live" connect the omnet++ simulation to an EXTERNAL TCP Server in order to provide external data to my simulation.

When I try to do something like: `winsock::socket(...)` I get the following error:

```
veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc:69:18: error: 'winsock' has not been declared.
```

I think it's because a function prototype and not part of winsock class were this would work I think.

But how can I tell my compiler to look into winsock.h where the function prototype for "socket" is this:

```cpp
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE SOCKET PASCAL socket (int, int, int);
```

I'm sure this is an easy question for every C++ expert.

Best regards,

Lukas

Comment: Try `::socket(...)`

Comment: The error message sounds like `socket` is actually a macro. You may be able to make this work by `#undef` ing the macro before including `winsock2.h` and hoping it wasn't already included indirectly... Alternatively you may be able to write a wrapper around the winsock socket logic and move it to a different target, but I don't know, if omnet++ can link targets compiled by other compilers...

Comment: This is not the first question I've seen where someone tried to use a header file as a namespace. Out of curiosity, why did you think `winsock::socket` would work?

Comment: Because I think it would work for a method socket of a class "winsock" right? It was a first guess before looking into winsock.h. I don't work with C++ regularly and...well..Knowledge fades away...